# jQuery ajax second post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I hit the submit button at the first time these codes works. But when I hit the second time to the button even if email and password values were true nothing happens and the user can not login. But if I write the true values at the first time, it works and user can login. So I figured the cause of this problem is about the "return false;" phrase. But if I remove return false; phrase, the form posts and ajax codes become useless. I must avoid the posting without ajax.
jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(){
        var email = $('#email').val();
        email = $.trim(email);
        var password = $('#password').val();
        password = $.trim(password);

            if(email == "") {
                $('#email').css({
                    "background-color": "#FF7070"
                });
                $('#box1').css({
                        "visibility": "visible"
                });
                return false;
            }else if(password == "") {
                $('#password').css({
                    "background-color": "#FF7070"
                });
                $('#box2').css({
                        "visibility": "visible"
                    });             
                return false;
            }else{

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(c) {
                        if(c == "no") {
                            $('#box3').css({
                                "visibility": "visible"
                            });
                            return false;
                        } else if (c == "ok") {
                            window.location.href = "homepage.php";
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(a, b) {
                        if (b == "timeout") {
                            alert("Error: #101");
                        }
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function(){
                            alert("Error: #102")
                        }
                    }
                  });
            }
           return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action="">
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Log in">
            </div>

            <div class="keep-login">
                <label for="remember">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" checked="checked">Remember me
                </label>
                <span><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
            </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'email' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('email'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

            if($login) {
                echo "ok";
            } else {
                echo "no";
            }

        } else {
            echo "no";       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing happens"? Doesn't the ajax request execute?

Comment: it doesn't request execute.

Comment: What's the error then? Do you get an exception? Doesn't it even enter the `click` handler? Does it go into the `email == ""` or `password == ""` branches even if it doesn't? Please do some debugging.

Comment: The problem is if I enter my email or password wrongly I can't log in this is okey. After that if I enter correct email and password(without refreshing the page) I can't log in again. Because it looks that button is disable.

Comment: But you didn't disable the button, did you? So please debug what happens when you click it.

Answer (score -1):

First, remove the method and action attributes of the form element. You can remove the form tag altogether but if you want to support non-javascript submissions, you'll need the form tag (however, the original question did not ask for this). You're 'submitting' the form via jQuery, so you don't need a method and an action on a form tag.

Input type="password" never autocompletes, so you don't need that attribute.

I also added an error div. Here is your new html:

```
<div id="error" style="display: none;">Login failed.</div>
<form>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Log in">
</div>

<div class="keep-login">
    <label for="remember">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" checked="checked">Remember me
    </label>
    <span><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
</div>
</form>
```

Replace your $.ajax statement with a $.post statement, and simply your logic.

```
$.post("ajax.php", { e: email, p: password }, function (data) {
    if (data == "ok") window.location.href = "homepage.php";
    else $("#error").slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp(); // I added div#error with "Failed to Login" message in the html above
});
```

This code will now redirect if the returned data is "ok"; otherwise, it will show div#error (again, this is in the html above), delay for 3 seconds, and then hide the message.

The `return false;` is unnecessary in each instance in your code above because after each conditional, the code ends - there is no other code to prevent from executing (which is why you would use `return false;` in this context).

You can do the $.trim on the same line as when you assign the variables, like I did with the slideUp, delay, and slideDown.

Comment: I replaced with your codes but now I always get login failed. Even if I write correct email and password at the first time.

Comment: @nijamitsu you have to change the parameters to whatever your $_POST[] is grabbing on the php end. Edit the `{ e: email, p: password }` to whatever post names you have set in the backend code (the `e` and the `p`). I would have done this for you, but you did not post your php code.

Comment: Looks like laravel since you're using `Input::get('email')` instead of `$_POST['email']` (same for other fields). Assuming Input::get() works for post variables, just change `Input::get('email')` to `Input::get('e')` and `Input::get('password')` to `Input::get('p')` to avoid ambiguity in the jQuery parameters and it should work. You need to also add the checkbox value to the array of parameters though.

Comment: I have tried a lot of combination with your codes but I always get login failed. I am new in jQuery and I can't handle it. So your jQuery codes are totally different from mine. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: The variable names that are being sent via the jquery are not the same as what the php is looking for. Change them in the php to match by doing what I said in the previous comment. If done correctly, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Of course I did but the problem is still same. But now I think root of the problem is my token system. I'm working on it.

Comment: -1 for removing the `<form>`. It's semantically useful if not even required, and it is necessary for a working submission when JS is disabled.

Comment: @Bergi You are correct about the semantics of it; however, the question does not explicitly ask nor does it imply that non-javascript support is required or desired. I have modified the answer to include the form tag in the code and to delve a little deeper into the form remarks for a better answer.

Comment: Non-javascript support is always desired, unobtrusive javascript is a best practise. I don't see any reason to remove `method` and `action`?